# Fix background-gradient with viewport for QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea

Please have a look at the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        color_gradient = QLinearGradient(1, 0, 1, 1)
        color_gradient.setSpread(QGradient.PadSpread)
        color_gradient.setCoordinateMode(QGradient.ObjectMode)
        color_gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor('#8000D3'))
        color_gradient.setColorAt(0.5, QColor('#CB5CFF'))
        color_gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor('#8000D3'))

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(color_gradient))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        # Set widget and layout
        self.scroll_widget = QWidget()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(30)
        self.scroll_widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        # Add Labels
        for _ in range(40):
            label = QLabel("test")
            self.layout.addWidget(label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    dialog = MyScrollArea()
    dialog.show()

    app.exec()
```

Currently, the gradient set as the background-brush scrolls with the scrollbar.

I know that I can set the background-image to be [fixed with the viewport](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qabstractscrollarea), but how can I fix the gradient instead?
The only option I can think of is to put the gradient in a separate label and overlay it with the QScrollArea, but I hope there is a simpler solution.

---

**To be more precise:**
I want that regardless of the position of the scrollbar, the background of the QScrollArea always looks like this (rotated to save space):

[image: Rotated Gradient]

That is the whole gradient should always be visible, and not just parts of it.

Comment: explain yourself better, what do you want to obtain?

Comment: @eyllanesc Note that the scrolling background only seems to work with fusion and window styles. Using breeze style the background doesn't scroll, with oxygen it doesn't even paint correctly.

Comment: fusion style uses the QPalette, and other styles like breeze or oxygen don't.Many styles do not use Qt Style Sheet or QPalette, and use predefined formats.

Comment: @eyllanesc well, they do, in their own way (which is kind of annoying, sometimes), but I was only pointing out that in case you didn't see the scrolling background because you were using another style as default.

Comment: I edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: @SirTeddytheFirst So, you don't want the gradient to be simply fixed, you want it to be *stretched* to the whole viewport, depending on the size (so it gets enlarged or reduced)?

Comment: @musicamante Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done using the palette, because the gradient background is painted on the "scrolling" widget, while you want to adapt it to the visible part of the viewport. Also, be aware that setting a palette on a widget automatically sets it to its children (due to property inheritance), so you should generally avoid that unless you are sure about its result.

The solution is to override the paintEvent of the scroll area and use that gradient for the viewport. In order to ensure that this works properly, the widget set for the scroll area must have a transparent background set.

```
class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # note that I've made the gradient an attribute of the instance, so it can
        # be used in the paint event without recreating it everytime;
        self.color_gradient = QLinearGradient(1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.color_gradient.setSpread(QGradient.PadSpread)
        self.color_gradient.setCoordinateMode(QGradient.StretchToDeviceMode)
        self.color_gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor('#8000D3'))
        self.color_gradient.setColorAt(0.5, QColor('#CB5CFF'))
        self.color_gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor('#8000D3'))

        # ...
        # set the transparent background **only** for the container widget; note
        # the period before QWidget;
        self.scroll_widget.setStyleSheet('.QWidget {background: transparent;}')

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self.viewport())
        qp.fillRect(self.viewport().rect(), self.color_gradient)
```